# Handling browser back SSR in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using server side rendering in nextjs(getServerSideProps) together with useswr to fetch and load data into an infinite scrolling list. When the user navigates back or forward I want to remember the scroll position and the data that was already loaded into the list. Currently when navigating using the browser back and forward buttons the whole page is reloaded again including requests to the server.

I don't think useswr handles caching on the ssr so I was considering to store the scroll position + data into cookies which can then be accessed during the SSR. However I am not sure how to correctly handle the browser states e.g. if the user navigates back a few times and then forward again or if he navigates to the same page at different time during the session. This would easily become difficult to keep track of.

I am aware of state machines but up till now I have simply been using context hooks and cookies to share data between client and server in nextjs.

What would be a good way to handle caching/restoring scroll position + ssr dynamic data in nextjs when the user navigates back or forward?